# Hudson CI: The user permission for shell script

Tags: hudson

I am setting up Hudson to run a shell script, which simply copy the workspace to a different folder. I got the following error:

> cp: cannot create directory
>   `/home/u123/Temp/workspace':
>   Permission denied

My question is, which user Hudson build is running? I installed Hudson as a Ubuntu service according to this page: http://pkg.hudson-labs.org/debian/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not ask hudson itself? Create a job and in that job have it run the command "id" and/or "whoami". The answer should be in the console output of the job.